# extract all the possible text from a webpage in R

Tags: r

I used this script to extract the text from a webpage

```
url <- "http://www.dlink.com/it/it"

doc <- getURL(url)

#get the text from the body
html <- htmlTreeParse(doc, useInternal = TRUE)
txt <- xpathApply(html, "//body//text()[not(ancestor::script)][not(ancestor::style)][not(ancestor::noscript)]", xmlValue)
txt<-toString(txt)
```

but the problem is that it takes just the words in the first page, how can I extend it to the whole website?

Comment: If your intention is to follow the links you may wish to have a look at [this article](http://francojc.github.io/web-scraping-with-rvest/). It describes how you can extract the links from the *main/landing* page and then extract the content from those.

Comment: You could scrape the links on the site map and then iterate, though there's no assurance that's exhaustive. I'm not sure of the point, though; all you'll get is a huge amount of unstructured data. Also check terms and conditions, of course; most companies are protective of the data on their websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with `rvest` to scrape the links and `purrr` to iterate:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

url <- "http://www.dlink.com/it/it"

r <- read_html(url) %>% 
    html_nodes('a') %>% 
    html_attr('href') %>% 
    Filter(function(f) !is.na(f) & !grepl(x = f, pattern = '#|facebook|linkedin|twitter|youtube'), .) %>% 
    map(~{
        print(.x)
        html_session(url) %>% 
            jump_to(.x) %>% 
            read_html() %>% 
            html_nodes('body') %>% 
            html_text() %>% 
            toString()
    })
```

I filtered out social nets and dead links from the list of links, some more tuning might be in order.

Be advised that you will be scraping a lot of garbage. Some more targeting on what to scrape inside each page might be needed (ie: something more specfic than the whole `body` tag)